# ASP.NET MVC How to populate an editorfor date picker with the date of a model's property

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a website that I am creating in ASP.NET with MVC structure and overall like the efficiency of creating and displaying data from a database over web forms. However, the issue I've run into is with Razor and the EditorFor helper. I know they recently added the ability to send HTML Attributes, which I have used with Bootstrap's date picker for a more friendly entry system. However, I can't find a way to populate the EditorFor with the model.Sale.Date of an existing record into the fields (like i did with the DropDownListFor helpers).

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sale.Date, new { @class = "control-label" })&nbsp;
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sale.Date, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Pick a date" })&nbsp;
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sale.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })&nbsp;

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })&nbsp;
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee.Id, new SelectList(Model.Employees.Employees, "Id", "FullName", Model.Sale.EmployeeId))&nbsp;
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })&nbsp;

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })&nbsp;
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Service.Id, new SelectList(Model.Services.Services, "Id", "Description", Model.Sale.ServiceId), null, null)&nbsp;
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })&nbsp;
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to accomplish this the easiest?

Comment: The date auto populates the editorfor in Safari because the bootstrap date picker isn't loading properly. But, in Chrome the bootstrap date picker is loading and won't show the auto populated date..

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to use the `@Html.EditorFor` and not just use `@Html.Textboxfor` ... Also bear in mind that the data attribute for the date should be `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` ( if it is not already )

Comment: I have it set to [DateType(DataType.Date)] in the ViewModel already. I only used the EditorFor because of the bootstrap css class for date picker working properly with EditorFor. Is there a easy way to do the population with TextBoxFor?

Comment: I was under the impression that by setting the attribute would automatically set the `Textboxfor` input to type `date` , I guess i am wrong. I normally use `textboxfor` and then add the class `.date` with the bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JQueryui` library and use The `DatePicker` [more info](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

It has a lot of features that you can easily implement in your razor views.
Your code will look like this:

```
 @Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(model => model.SaleDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SaleDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of JQueryUI, I added it to the project and will try using it sometime.

Comment: It's a great library , JQuery friendly and has a lot of features that you can explore. if you work a lot with time manipulation in your code , i also recommend th elibrary timejs.

Comment: I dont agree , I think jquery ui is terrible and passed its sell by date. You get a lot stuff you will probably never hit in app. It should also be noted that the `@Html.JQueryUI` helper is not default . I am assuming it is apart of [this](http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/)

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't quickly implement the JQueryUI function earlier today when I tried it and am still looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: what was your problem with the implementation?

Comment: @gerdi can you explain/prove why Jquery-UI is "terrible and passed its sell by date"?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I take it back. jquery ui is actually really good. I dont know why but for some reason i was under the impression that you had to download all the components even if you just need one of them. In some cases i can see where other libs would be better for certain functionality , but it does have some good stuff

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem like that:
`<input id="FechaCita" name="FechaCita" type="date" class="form-control mr-2" min="@Model.SetUpMinMax.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" value="@Model.FechaCita.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />`

when i was making tests in the console of my web browser i see that the format that has the date in the browse was no the same that i use so i change the format to see and everything works

but iven when i have to use a task and not a @html helper of razor because it pass again the sent forma. i could user a anotation format but i save my date in english so i let it like that.